# Which languages do Perl-compatible regular expressions recognize?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions

As the title says, I spent a couple of hours last weekend trying to wrap up my mind about the class of languages matched by Perl-compatible regular expressions, *excluding any matching operator that allows to execute arbitrary code inside the pattern*.

If you don't know what PCREs are, please read [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) and [this](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt).

The problem is, the resources available on internet pretty much stop at context-free languages, and PCREs can match more than those (see below); but I really don't know where to find more theorems or papers about this kind of stuff.

In particular: PCREs are obviously a superset of regular languages (as the PCRE syntax has all the regular language operators).

Any CFG can be put in Greibach normal form, which removes left recursion. I think this can be used by means of `(?(DEFINE)...)` groups to "translate" the grammar into matching subroutines, avoiding to choke on left recursion, by translating:

- the non-terminal at the head of each production becomes a subroutine `(?<HEAD>...)`
- the body of each production is put in the subroutine; terminals are left as-is, non-terminals become procedure invocations (i.e. `(?&NONTERMINAL)`);
- all the productions with the same nonterminal as head are ORed together by means of the `|` operator (plus additional grouping with `(?:...)`, if necessary)
- the pattern then becomes a `(?(DEFINE)...)` group containing all the "translated" productions, and an invocation for the procedure of the starting symbol, to match the entire string, i.e. `^(?(DEFINE)...)(?&START)$`

This should deal with any CFG. Therefore, PCREs should be able to match any CFL.

There's more: let's take the simple language
$$L = \{ ww | w \in \Lambda^* \} $$
i.e. the language of the strings repeated twice. This language is not a CFL -- the pumping lemma for CFLs fails. (Pay particular attention that 
$$ |vxw| \leq p$$
must hold, thus you can't just pump the beginnings or the ends of the two repeated strings.)

However, this language is easily matched by a PCRE: `^(.*)\1$`. Therefore, we're strictly above CFLs.

How much above? Well, as I said, I have no idea. I couldn't find any resources about CSLs or all the other classes in between to make up my mind. Any expert willing to discuss this?

**Addendum:** I was asked to specify exactly which subset of the PCRE syntax must be allowed. As I wrote at the beginning of the post, I wanted to exclude any operator that allows to execute arbitrary code inside of the pattern, such as `??{}`.

For the argument's sake, I think we can stick with the syntax defined by the [pcresyntax(3)](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt) man page, which is a reasonable subset of what Perl 5.10-5.12 offers, minus the callouts (as they're not inside the pattern). I'm not sure that adding or removing backtracking control verbs change the language we can recognize; if so, it would be nice to figure out which classes we get with and without those.

Comment: Please include your chosen definition of PCRE in your question, as it has changed between versions. The real Perl regexes can contain arbitrary Perl code, making them Turing-complete.

Comment: I added a note at the end, I hope it makes this point more clear.

Answer (score 11):

I've also found this blog post extremely interesting http://nikic.github.io/2012/06/15/The-true-power-of-regular-expressions.html. It provides the very same proof I gave before about the fact that regexps recognizes the CFLs (by rewriting the grammar through `DEFINE` blocks), and even some CSLs (like the language of repeated strings); it builds on that and goes on, giving a proof that regexps with backreferences are NP-hard (by reducing 3-SAT to a regexp).

Comment: When the author says "NP-complete" they should be saying "NP-hard".  They provide no proof that the class of PCRE languages is contained in NP.

Comment: True, it's also noted in the comments.

Comment: The language of PCRE is in PSPACE, which is obvious since an implementation which uses polynomial space exists. While it's not a proof, it feels to me like the subset of PCRE without greedy operators is likely to be NP, because that would only require finding some match; greedy operators direct the search to a specific match.

Answer (score 7):

They decide at most the context-sensitive languages (which, as you point out, is a superset of the context-free languages). See [this perl monks post](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=809842).

The basic insight is that the "memory" of the machine is the number of capture groups, which is linearly bounded.

Comment: The argument you give in the second paragraph explains why PCRE can not accept *more* than CS, but not why this inclusion is exact (which you suggest in your first paragraph). It does not seem as if the linked article gave a proof of that, either.

Comment: Well, you can't group more than what's in the input string, and the number of groups is fixed in a given pattern, so you have an upper (linear) limit to the memory a pattern uses. Still, I miss a formal proof of a PCRE -> linear bounded automaton transformation...

Comment: Yes, you two are right. I have modified the answer.

Comment: See also http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=406253 for an earlier discussion.

Answer (score 6):

OP already linked an [awesome blog post](http://nikic.github.io/2012/06/15/The-true-power-of-regular-expressions.html). I did some more research on it, and found the following pieces of information:

- [Wikipedia article on Context-sensitive grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar#Formal_definition) mentions that right-context-sensitive grammars can express all general CSGs (at the end of section, near reference 13). Unfortunately, neither that nor the referenced page shows *how* to find an equivalent right-CSG for a given CSG.
- The blog post shows that lookbehind and lookahead assertions can be used to specify left and right context (α and β in αAβ → αγβ) respectively. Lookbehind is limited to fixed-length, but lookahead is not restricted at all.

Assuming both sources are true, any given CSG can be converted to a right-CSG, which can be expressed in Perl regex using lookahead. Therefore, **Perl regexes are strong enough to match all CSGs.**