# Formal Class of Languages Describable by .NET Regular Expressions

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions

This is sort of a computer science question and sort of a programming question.  What is the name of the formal class of languages that can be described by .NET regular expressions (assuming it a well known class)?  For instance formal regular expressions describe the class of regular languages but .NET regular expressions (as with most modern regular expression engines) are more powerful than formal regular expressions and therefore describe a larger class of languages.

This is basically the same question as this [Which languages do Perl-compatible regular expressions recognize?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/4839/which-languages-do-perl-compatible-regular-expressions-recognize) but for .NET regular expressions instead of perl regular expressions.   However as far as I can tell, this question was never answered completely either.

Comment: What makes you think .NET regexes (or any "modern regular expression engines") are more expressive than regexes as defined in language theory?

Comment: The answers to the question the OP linked to show that there exists at least one modern regular expression engine that can recognize at least some and at most all context-sensitive languages, which is more expressive than being able to recognize only the regular languages.

Comment: I don't think there is a specific pre-existing class of languages that exactly matches what .NET regular expressions can match. So, the trivial answer to your question is that .NET regular expressions can recognize the class of .NET regular expression recognizable languages.