# Difference between pattern matching and pattern searching in terms of DFA/Regex

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions, search-algorithms

E.g.

**Matching Problem** The DFA of regex `good` is like a chain.

```
match:     "good"
not match: "people do not give good comments are not good people"
```

**Searching Problem** The DFA used in searching regex `good` could be:

[image]

```
1 matching:  "good"
2 matchings: "people do not give good comments are not good people"
```

Here are the questions:

1. In the above two problems, it seems the searching problem's DFA is the matching problem's DFA plus some backedges and an additional state (here state `0`). Is this the difference in general?
2. What is the regex of searching problem in this case?

Comment: [This answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2557/how-to-simulate-backreferences-lookaheads-and-lookbehinds-in-finite-state-auto/2560#2560) contains some related thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

This is true in general, in a way.
Consider a regex $r$. You can construct a DFA (or NFA) for the matching problem. Denote this NFA by $A$.

To solve the searching problem, you can proceed in several ways.
First, you can just solve the matching problem for the regex $\Sigma^*\cdot r\cdot \Sigma^*$.

Alternatively, you can construct an equivalent NFA for the latter regex. The form of such an NFA would be an initial state that guesses when $r$ starts (at which point there is a transition to the initial states of $A$), and every accepting state of $A$ moves to an accepting sink.

This NFA can be thought of as a generalization of the situation you describe. Indeed, when you determinize it, the equivalent DFA essentially tracks $r$, and whenever it fails the DFA "resets". This is not exact, since it strongly depends on $r$.

When $A$ is a chain, then indeed determinizing the NFA yields a DFA that follows the chain, and whenever there is a "mistake" (that is, $r$ is not met), it resets to the initial state. However, it could be that resetting might not go as far as the initial state. For example, when searching for $aba$, if you see $aa$, then the second $a$ should not reset all the way back, but rather to the second state, since the second $a$ may be the start of the regex's occurrence.