# When is a regexp not a Regular Expression?

Tags: regular-expressions

Since I'm studying for my formal languages college course, I stumbled upon these fascinating posts ([One](http://neilk.net/blog/2000/06/01/abigails-regex-to-test-for-prime-numbers/) [Two](http://blog.kenficara.com/2013/06/30/irregular-language-and-regular-expressions/)) which describe how to find a prime number using a *regexp*. As I said, a ***regexp***, not a **regular expression**.
Since a regular expression can match strings computed by a Finite State Automata and finding a prime number can't be done by a FSA, the regexp shown in the blog post is not **entirely** a regular expression since it does backtracking to match the string.

Since I've never really used any regular expression, now, my question:

*How can I immediately recognize a regexp from a "true" regular expression just by looking at it?*

Definitions: By regular expression, I refer to the notion as defined in formal languages.  By regexp, I mean the notion supported by modern programming languages; the regexp syntax often contains additional features, such as backreferences.  Regexps as seen in programming languages are [strictly more powerful](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/4839/755) than formal languages style regular expressions.

Comment: Regexp is just an abbreviation of regular expression. The prime numbers calculation is based on a Perl hack, not on regular expressions.

Comment: It's rather simple. Regular languages employ concatenation, repetition and alternation. Anytime an engine supports something not equivalent to these, it's non-regular.

Comment: Related questions: [1](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2557/98), [2](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/4839/which-languages-do-perl-compatible-regular-expressions-recognize?rq=1), [3](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/24031/98).

Comment: @Yannis If you jump over the fence to CS, that's no longer true. Regexps as seen in programming languages are strictly more powerful than (formal languages style) regular expressions, and the short form "regexp" is by convention (I don't know how widespread a one it is) used for the former, not the latter kind.

Comment: @KilianFoth That's not really a helpful description, though. For example, you can add negation (or, indeed, any finite set of Boolean connectives) to regular expressions without increasing their power.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

tl;dr backrefs.

As soon as there is a `\1` (or any number that isn't used to escape unicode) in the regexp it is not a regular expression.

Backrefs allows you to match `(a+)b\1` which matches n times `a` followed by b followed by n times `a` for any n>1. This is not a regular language (it's the poster child of a non regular language).

It is necessary and nearly sufficient that the backref references a group that contains a regexp that matches an arbitrarily long string or that it contains a `*` or `+`. The only exception (that I found) of a regexp of the form `(A)B\1` where A is a finite language (could be replaced by a enumeration of all words that accepts them). You can convert it to `word1+Bword1|word2+Bword2` etc. because A is finite.

Look-around groups don't remove the regularness of the regexp. `A(?=B)C` is the cross-section of regexes `AB.*` and `AC` and the cross-section of 2 regular languages is regular. Negative lookahead is similar except using the complement of `B.*` (complements of regular languages being regular). Lookbehind is exactly the same as well `A(?<=B)C` is the cross-section of `AC` and `.*BC`.

Comment: Is this necessary and sufficient? It looks to me like `(a)\1`, while using a backref, is equivalent to `aa` and therefore trivially Regular. I'm also wondering if lookahead assertions can use to recognize non-Regular languages.

Comment: @MSalters: If you want to get really technical, `(a)\1` is not a regular expression, but recognizes a regular language.

Comment: Look-around aren't always a simple intersection: `^A*(?=AB)B` matches nothing, while the intersection of `^A*AB` and `^A*B` matches `AAB`. Though I'm pretty sure they're still regular.

Comment: @assembly_wizard yeah I was assuming that there is no overlap where A and B could be. More formally `A(?=B)C` is `A` concatenated with intersection of `B` and `C`. (with the same reasoning)