# Can every single regular expression be translated into deterministic finite automata?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

Can every regex be translated into a DFA? Or only a subset of regular expressions?

If so, what is an example of a regular expression that cannot be translated into a DFA?

Comment: This is *so* general reference. Literally *every* resource talking on regular languages will hand you the answer. What have you read?

Comment: That said, if you are talking regexp, not regular expressions, answers are different but still easy. Consider `(.*)\1`, for instance, which isn't even context-free.

Comment: [Related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/38451/when-a-regexp-is-not-a-regular-expression), with links to more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every regular expression using only *,+,| (but not, say, backreferences) can be converted into a DFA. This is shown in textbooks on formal languages. Modern regular expressions, as used in actual programming languages, are more powerful than classical ones, and in particular they can recognize non-regular languages, such as the language of squares $w^2$, which is recognized by `(.*)\1`.

Answer (score 3):

A regular expression can only describe a regular language, but it can describe all regular languages. The same is valid for DFA: They can only describe regular languages, but they can describe all regular languages.

So if a regular expression can describe a language, that language is regular, and can be described by a DFA. You can construct such DFA by using Thompson or Glushkov construction (among others) to construct an NFA, and then convert it to a DFA.

If a language is produced by a DFA, it is regular, and can be described by a regular expression. To construct a regular expression from a DFA, have a look at [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions).

Note: Outside of theory, people often confuse regular expressions with languages designed for programming, for example PCREs. While they are named "Perl Compatible *regular expressions*", they are much more powerful than regular expressions or DFA. They can in fact [decide some NP-complete problems](http://perl.plover.com/NPC/NPC-3SAT.html).