# Regular expressions and 'capturing parentheses' with 'backreferences'

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions

We know that regular expressions (RE) are implemented with finite automata (FA). In some language (like JavaScript) in RE there are features like 'capturing parenthesis' with 'backreferences':

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-capturing-parentheses

*(x)
Matches 'x' and remembers the match, as the following example shows. The parentheses are called capturing parentheses.
The '(foo)' and '(bar)' in the pattern /(foo) (bar) \1 \2/ match and remember the first two words in the string "foo bar foo bar". The \1 and \2 in the pattern match the string's last two words.*

I want to know if this pattern `/(foo) (bar) \1 \2/` is in fact a RE according the definition of RE that we have in theoretical formal language or it is something more powerful. And if it is so I would like to know if this kind of feature is implemented also with FA or in another way (in particualr how it is implemented).

Comment: See http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/4839/755 and http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/38451/755 and http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/24031/755.

Comment: See https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html for a great writeup on the real-world (implementation level) performance implications of this difference.  (Edit: I see it's already been linked to from [this answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/69213/40670).)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The RE in the Automata Theory are equivalent to FA, but for the programming languages (regexp) this is no longer true.

The regular expressions in the programming languages (like PCRE) are far more powerfull than Regular Expressions (type 3) in the Automata Theory.

The matching parenthesis is neither regular nor context-free, it is a context-sensitive feature. But the RegExp from the question does not fully support Type 2 or Type 1.

The bracket matching is not implemented via FA. In case of PCRE it is implemented by guessing and backtracking.

Take a look at Perl Monks description about [PCRE](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=809842).

Comment: Thank you. Then, in this case, RegExp is an abuse of (formal) language.

Comment: Well, it is the name collision. The very initial idea was something like RE, but even when it evolved, the name remained.

Comment: @asv: For some time after capturing was introduced the RE with capture groups was called extended regexp or ERE. Then for some time after Perl introduced their version of RE it was called regex to differentiate it from POSIX standardised regexp and ERE (note regex vs regexp). These days people don't care.

Answer (score 9):

These extended notions of regular expressions capture more than just the regular languages.  For example, `([ab]*)\1` matches the language $\{ww\mid w\in\{a,b\}^*\}$, which isn't regular and isn't even context-free (Example 2.38 of Sipser, *Introduction to the Theory of Computation*, 3rd edition).

"Regular" expressions that don't match regular langauges can't be translated to finite automata, since finite automata match only the regular languages. A side-effect of this is that many libraries don't even try to compile to automata, which can lead to extremely slow matching, even when a "regular" expression is a true regular expression. Russ Cox wrote an [excellent article](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) about this, which goes into a lot of the history, too.

Comment: Thank you for your example and for these informations. :)

Answer (score 8):

The answers are probably answering what you're *intending* to ask, but not what you're asking.

> I want to know if this pattern `/(foo) (bar) \1 \2/` is in fact a RE according the definition of RE that we have in theoretical formal language or it is something more powerful. And if it is so I would like to know if this kind of feature is implemented also with FA or in another way (in particualr how it is implemented).

In fact this **is** a regular expression that can be implemented with a finite automaton, because `\1` is *guaranteed* to evaluate to `foo` and `\2` is *guaranteed* to evaluate to `bar`.

Therefore a regex engine could use this fact to actually create a finite automaton that exactly describes the language you proposed.

However, if you make any captures *conditional*, then this may become false, as others have mentioned.

(Note that I say you ***may*** have trouble, because a language like `/(a(aa|aa)|(aa|aa)a)\1\2/` can *still* be described via a FA. <strike>I only gave you a necessary condition, not a sufficient one.</strike> **Edit:** It just occurred to me that having a conditional is neither necessary nor sufficient, as `/(a*)\1/` can also be turned into a finite automaton whereas `/(ab*)\1/` cannot. So I guess it was just a rule of thumb.)

Comment: Ok some particual pattern with 'capturing parenthesis' can be RE. Good observation.

Comment: @asv: Yup. Also, I think another thing that is misleading about all answers here (including mine) is that the problem isn't the capturing parentheses themselves, but the backreferences that refer to them. I remember reading that capturing parentheses can be handled without backtracking as long as there are no backreferences. However, I don't know the details behind whether this can be really done using finite automata or not (my impression is it can, but I don't exactly know how). But there should be other ways to handle them without backtracking, such as via LR parsing or something like that.

Comment: Yes, the question is: backreferences

Answer (score 0):

Certain regex implementation does not build a DFA. For example, `java.util.regex` [OpenJDK](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Pattern.java) implementation does not. As a result, its matching time is slower than DFA compiled implementation like [dk.brics.automaton](http://www.brics.dk/automaton/). Yet the later does not support capturing group as a result of underlying implementation.

Comment: Remember that NFA->DFA construction can be very expensive (2^#nodes).

Comment: Oh yes, thank you for pointing that out. I've updated my answer to reflect that only matching time of DFA based impl is shorter.