# Algorithms to match regular expressions containing backreferences

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-expressions, linear-bounded-automata

I'm trying to come up with an implementation of a matcher for regular expressions containing [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) like:

`([a-c])x\1` which would match `axa`, `bxb` and `cxc` but nothing else.

While I've seen a number of [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28941425/capture-groups-using-dfa-based-linear-time-regular-expressions-possible) about the theory about what is the class of languages this type of regexes describe, I didn't manage to find some more concrete implementation details beyond the fact that matchers for `Context Sensitive Languages` are `Linear Bound Automata`.

Could you point out some resources about the implementation of such matchers?

**UPDATE:** Currently this is my best reference: ["Extending Finite Automata to Efficiently Match Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions"](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4261/09377b5312fe7102d4fd9558e83e42347bff.pdf)

PS: These regex features are supported by most standard libraries of modern programming languages (Perl, Java, C# etc), but I wouldn't start there since I believe those implementations are quite terse.

Comment: Implementation is off-topic here. Algorithms are on-topic.

Comment: [Closely related question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2557/98).