# No FSM/Regex exists for this language right?

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions

The language is this:

$L = \{w \in \{a,b\}*:$ each $a$ has a matching $b$ somewhere in $w$ $\}$

This wouldn't have an FSM since you'd need infinite states of depth for each unmatched a you have, right?

Comment: What do you mean by "matching"? Do you mean the number of $a$ is no more than the number of $b$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate backreferences, lookaheads, and lookbehinds in finite state automata?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2557/how-to-simulate-backreferences-lookaheads-and-lookbehinds-in-finite-state-auto)

Comment: Or do you mean: a bijective mapping can be constructed between the $a$s and the $b$s? (In other words, the number of $a$s and $b$s is equal.)

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Daniel Martin's answer.
None of the following interpretations yields a regular language:

- $L = \{ w \in \{a,b\}^*  : \exists n \ge 0,  \; w = a^n b^n \}$
- $L$ contains all the words $w \in \{a,b\}^*$ such that the number of $a$s in $w$ is not larger than the number of $b$s in $w$.
- $L$ contains all the words $w \in \{a,b\}^*$ such that the number of $a$s in $w$ is equal than the number of $b$s in $w$.
- $L$ contains all the words $w \in \{a,b\}^*$ such that there is a injective/bijective mapping that maps each a $a$ that appears in a generic position $i$ in $w$ with a $b$ in $w$ that appears in a position $j>i$.

The proof is the same for all cases: if $L$ was regular then,
for a sufficiently large $n$, the word $w = a^n b^n \in L$ could be written as $w = a^{n-k} a^k b^n$ (with $1 \le k \le n)$ in such a way that $a^{n-k}a^{k \cdot h} b^n \in L$ for all choices of $h \in \mathbb{N}$ (see [pumping lemma for regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages)).
This is a contradiction since $a^{n-k}a^{2k} b^n = a^{n+k}b^{n} \not\in L$.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say, it isn't completely clear what you mean by "matching", but if you mean that for any positive integer $n$, the string $\mathtt{a}^n\mathtt{b}^n$ (that is, the string of $n$ "$\mathtt{a}$"s followed by $n$ "$\mathtt{b}$"s) is in the language, but $\mathtt{a}^n\mathtt{b}^{n-1}$ is *not* in the language, then what you say is correct: $L$ is not a regular language because you would need an infinite number of states, at least one for every string of the form $\mathtt{a}^n$.