# Is regex with lookaround still regular?

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions

It is well known that "regex" with back-reference is not a regular expression anymore.
For instance, `(.*)\1` matches any string repeated twice.
However, is it possible to construct a DFA for regex with lookaround?

I found [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2557) and particularly [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2560), which says

> Look-ahead and look-behind are nothing special in the world of finite automata as we only match whole inputs here. Therefore, the special semantic of "just check but don't consume" is meaningless; **you just concatenate and/or intersect checking and consuming expressions and use the resulting automata.**

(emphasis mine)

However, I'm not quite sure how to intersect the checking and matching automata.
For simple cases such as `foo(?=bar)`, I can just concatenate them (`foobar`).
But this won't work for more complex cases such as `foo(?=bar)(?=baz)`:
since lookahead will not consume the input,
what follows `foo` must match both `bar` and `baz`.

[This answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/69736) suggests using [Alternating Finite Automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_finite_automaton),
but after reading through the tremendously <del>un</del>helpful Wikipedia page,
I am totally confused how this can help turn lookarounds into plain old DFA.

Comment: None of your sources contains a definition of lookahead or lookbehind, making it difficult to answer the question. In particular, I'm not sure how to interpret more than one of each.

Answer (score 4):

Lookaround assertions do not extend expressive power of regular expressions: it is still the set of regular languages. See [1] for proof. There is also a reference to the paper [2] where they prove this by conversion to a DFA.

[1] Berglund M, van der Merwe B, van Litsenborgh S (2021) Regular Expressions with Lookahead. JUCS - Journal of Universal Computer Science 27(4): 324-340. https://doi.org/10.3897/jucs.66330

[2] Takayuki Miyazaki, Yasuhiko Minamide, Derivatives of Regular Expressions with Lookahead, Journal of Information Processing, 2019, Volume 27, Pages 422-430, Released on J-STAGE June 15, 2019, Online ISSN 1882-6652, https://doi.org/10.2197/ipsjjip.27.422

Comment: Thank you for your contribution to the site!  Might you be willing to add a full reference/citation to the paper (with title, authors, and where published)?

Comment: Sure, I have just done it.